# Programming discrete fourier coefficients in matlab

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, fourier-series

Alright so I am having the following issue:  I want to figure out how to find the fourier coefficients of the following function:
$$D(X)=\frac {a'(x)} {1+a'(x)^2}$$

Where $a(x)$ is an arbitrary function.  I already have a model for finding the fourier coefficients for $a(x)$ and $a'(x)$:

```
fc = fft(a) / Nfft;
fc = fftshift(fc);                % fft of a(x)
fc = conj(fc);                    % sign correction
aprimec = -i * [0:Dim2-1] .* fc;  % fc of derivative (definition)
```

The equation I am given to use is:
$$f_m=\frac 1 N \sum^Nf_ie^{+im2\pi x}$$

Which confuses me because of the $f_i$.  So does any one have any suggestions?

Additionally, I do not know how to define d

```
d = diff(a)/(1+diff(a)^2);
```

I do not think that this would work because doesn't `diff(x)` just take the difference between two consecutive components in the vector?

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing in the example matlab code? Why are you conjugating? What is Dim2? What is the point of the (incomplete) summation formula you gave? What is it about the $f_i$ that you don't understand? What is $d$ suppose to be? If you have $a$, then why cant you just estimate $a'$ and then take the FT of $a' / ( 1 + (a')^2 )$?

Answer (score 1):

The DFT is isomorphic, so if you have the DFT coefficients for $a'$, then all you need to do to get $a'$ is apply the inverse DFT:

```
D = ifft(aprimec) ./ (1 + ifft(aprimec).^2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to approximate $D$ using the `ifft` of $a'$, additionally your formula seems to be
$$ \hat{f}_m = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f_j \omega_N^{mj} $$
where $\omega_N = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{N})$.

Comment: How would I approximate D?

Comment: @JamesMaslek If you already have $a'$, then why is it that you can't find $D$?